# Private secondary interface on OpenVZ container

Tags: networking, routes, openvz

I am trying to create a secondary private interface to communicate between 2 openvz containers.

I have tried the steps indicated in the manual here: http://openvz.org/Virtual_Ethernet_device

Doing this I am able to get the container to communicate with the br0 interface I have created on the host machine but the host machine cannot communicate with the container and the containers cannot talk to eachother.

If anyone has experience with this can you share how you accomplished it?

Comment: I have also tried bridging the veth interfaces onto br0, that did not work either.

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer? or were  you able to solve this?